# In access VBA, Is there a way to look-up a record in a table using a combo-box criteria and adding that record to a different table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use unbound comboBoxes and textBoxes where a user a updates the controls and clicks on a button and a new record is created in another `tblEntry` using some data of the same record from `tblItems`. 
Problem: My code only works on the first record. It creates the new record in the `tblEntry` using data of the first record in `tblItems`. Can someone have a look please?

```
Private Sub addItem_Click()

Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblItems")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblEntry")

If Not IsNull(Me.combo1) Then
  rs2.AddNew
  rs2.Fields("Description").Value = rs1.Fields("Description").Value
  rs2.Fields("ItemNo").Value = rs1.Fields("ItemNo").Value
  rs2.Fields("ItemName").Value = Me.txtItemName.Value
  rs2.Fields("entryDate").Value = Me.txtentryDate.Value
  rs2.Update

Form.frmItemEntryDatasheet.Requery

End If

rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
rs2.Close
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Apply filter criteria for rs1 SQL to retrieve desired record. Why are you duplicating item data into tblEntry and not just saving tblItems primary key? Why would you even need rs1 and not just save values by referencing controls?

Comment: @June7 tblEntry is a small empty table which resides in the front end, it is used to generate information based on the user input and in turn is used to fill up a report which is templated to look like a document form. tblEntry is normally cleared from time to time.

Comment: You now have an answer but I still don't see need for rs1. Controls already have data, just reference them to save values. If values are in various combobox columns, use column index to grab, index begins with 0: `Me.combo1.Column(2)`. In fact, this record creation can be done with an INSERT action SQL and rs2 would not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @June7 says, there probably is no reason to do this. However, what you need to do is to open rs1 up filtered to just show data relating to that selected in combo1. Assuming that the first column in combo1 is the Primary Key from tblItem and called "ItemID":

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ItemDescription, ItemNo FROM tblItems WHERE ItemID ='" & ItemID.Value & "'")
```

I have also renamed your field "Description" to "ItemDescription" as it is probably a reserved word within Access and may case problems. I have also just selected the 2 fields that you are going to use - there is no point getting all of the fields. You should be opening both recordsets within the If/End If statement.

Also, when you are opening rs2, you are effectively selecting the whole table. Far better is to use:

```
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblEntry WHERE 1 = 2")
```

This opens up a recordset based on tblEntry, but with no records selected, and so therefore has less overhead.

Regards,